# X509Store is always empty on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, x509certificate2, pfx

I am able to install certificates using the following dotnet tool: https://github.com/gsoft-inc/dotnet-certificate-tool

After installation, I can confirm that the PFX files show up in the '~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my' location, as file named in the format, {thumbprint}.pfx.

However, when I try and access the x509 store in the following way:

```
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certCollection = store.Certificates;
```

My certCollection is always empty. Any ideas on why this is happening on my Linux machine?

Comment: The two things that come to mind are a) you're running the import and "read" as a different user, and b) when you're running your "read" code $HOME has been set to redirect ~ to a different location.

Comment: @bartonjs I've confirmed the app runs as the correct user by printing the result from Environment.Username. I had not considered that the $HOME location could have been redirected. Is there a way to test this from a debug log in my app?

Comment: Logging the value of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME")` would give that specific item (and compare it to where you think ~ is).  You may want to then also run the app under `strace` to see where it looked for the certificates.